# How do I get different column value based on condition in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset that look like

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 'DATE_11': ['1/1/2011','1/2/2015', '1/3/2015','1/4/2012','1/5/2011','1/6/2011','1/7/2011','1/8/2009',
  '1/9/2016','1/2/2015','1/3/2015','1/4/2015','1/5/2015','1/6/1998','1/7/2011'],
 'Column_1': ['A','B','S','A','B','S','A','A','C','A','A','A','A','A','A'],
                   'DATE_22': ['1/1/2015','1/2/2013', '1/3/2012','1/4/2015','1/5/2015','1/6/2015','1/7/2015','1/8/2015',
  '1/9/2016','1/2/2015','1/3/2015','1/4/2015','1/5/2015',np.nan,'1/7/2011'],
 'Column_2': ['A','A','A','A','B','B','A','A','B','S','A','A','A','A','A'],
                   'DATE_3': ['1/1/2016','1/2/2015', '1/3/2015','1/4/2015','1/5/2015','1/6/2015','1/7/2015','1/8/2015',
  '1/1/2016','1/2/2011','1/3/2001','1/4/2002','1/5/2006','1/6/1998','1/7/2011'],
 'Column_S': ['A','A','B','S','B','B','A','B','S','A','A','E','D','A','C']})
```

Here, I need to get minimum of 3 dates and get column value and column name that fulfills the condition

Here Column_1--DATE_11, Column_2--DATE_22 and DATE_3-- Column_S are 3 pairs.

I got the minimum of DATE_11, DATE_22, DATE_3 by

```
df[['DATE_11','DATE_22','DATE_3']] = df[['DATE_11','DATE_22','DATE_3']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%m/%d/%Y')

df['min_result'] = df[['DATE_11','DATE_22','DATE_3']].min(axis = 1)
```

But how do I get Column Value and column name. For example, I need to get "Column_1", "A" as 2 column value since minimum comes from DATE_11 and it is paired with Column_1.
For last 2 row, all value are same or 2 values are same and 1 is null, we can just leave both column as null so np.nan, np.nan as the result.

Can you please at least direct me to some function/module that can do this? I am completely lost at how I can do this.

Expected Result :

[image]
SOrry I dont know how to create tabular here so adding picture

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Can you add the expected output for the given sample?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, I have added expected output for the given sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

divide `df` and concat

```
df1 = (pd.concat([df.iloc[:, 1:3].rename(columns={'DATE_11':'DATE'}), 
                  df.iloc[:, 3:5].rename(columns={'DATE_22':'DATE'}), 
                  df.iloc[:, 5:7].rename(columns={'DATE_3':'DATE'})])
       .sort_values('DATE'))
```

`df1.head(5)`

```
    DATE        Column_1    Column_2    Column_S
0   1/1/2011    A           NaN         NaN
0   1/1/2015    NaN         A           NaN
0   1/1/2016    NaN         NaN         A
8   1/1/2016    NaN         NaN         S
9   1/2/2011    NaN         NaN         A





(df1.groupby(level=0).head(1)
 .set_index('DATE', append=True).stack().reset_index([1, 2]).sort_index()
 .set_axis(['min_result', 'column_N', 'column value'], axis=1))
```

result:

```
    min_result  column_N    column value
0   1/1/2011    Column_1    A
1   1/2/2013    Column_2    A
2   1/3/2012    Column_2    A
3   1/4/2012    Column_1    A
4   1/5/2011    Column_1    B
5   1/6/2011    Column_1    S
6   1/7/2011    Column_1    A
7   1/8/2009    Column_1    A
8   1/1/2016    Column_S    S
9   1/2/2011    Column_S    A
10  1/3/2001    Column_S    A
11  1/4/2002    Column_S    E
12  1/5/2006    Column_S    D
13  1/6/1998    Column_1    A
14  1/7/2011    Column_S    C
```

if you want, make value of `row 13` to null

and you can concat df1 & result